# How to fetch data from different sources on the internet with Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am coding an application where I want to fetch megavideo, spike,live video, youtube ,facebook, etc......so how can solve 
IS there any method in rails 3 ?

I looked everywhere on the net for a solution but it all seems very confusing too me.
Do anyone know of a good, simple gem that I can use for remote APIs? It was so simple in PHP.

Thankful for all input!

Comment: fetch youtube, facebook? fetch what exactly? there are gems for each specific api available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many

Youtube : https://github.com/kylejginavan/youtube_it

Facebook : http://facebooker.rubyforge.org/ and http://rfacebook.rubyforge.org/

Google : http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/articles/gdata_on_rails.html

Comment: I appreciate with your answer but when I want to fetch from MEGAVIDEO ,SPIKE at a time what will I do ????